# Proper External Variable Declarations and Definitions

Tags: c, extern

What is the accepted standard way to define an exposed variable in C? Suppose the setup is the following:

In .h

```
typedef struct my_struct{
...
} my_struct;

extern my_struct var1;
```

In .c

```
my_struct var1;
```

Is this proper usage or is the compiler doing unnecessary work here? What is the extern actually doing here? My understanding has always been that everything already has an implicit extern by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a small difference between the implicit `extern` part when it comes to variables and functions.

If you put

```
void foo(void);
```

in a .h file and include the .h file in multiple .cc files, there is no harm since the function is not defined in the .h file. It's only declared.

If you put,

```
int x;
```

in the same .h file, then `x` is defined in every .c file that includes the .h file. You would get similar error for the function if the .h file had:

```
void foo(void){}
```

since that is a declaration as well as a definition.

To make a variable such as `x` to be only a declaration, you need to add the `extern` keyword.

Comment: I don't know how to give one of these credit for the answer, because they are all helping me understand just exactly what is going on with the compiler. This is very helpful.

Comment: @SeaNick You can compile all the answers and create an answer that includes ideas that you learnt from all the answers.

Answer (score 2):

> My understanding has always been that everything already has an implicit extern by default.

This is true, however...

The purpose of explicitly `extern`ing `var1` in the header is to:

1. Document your intentions, that `var1` is not private.
2. Notify the compiler that source files that `include` the header are using a variable declared elsewhere.

**Recommendation**

Create getter/setter functions and make `var1` private (`static`).

Comment: That recommendation raises another point: The getter/setter methods are the only way of really ensuring that multiple .c files are creating defines for this variable and using them incorrectly, right?

Comment: @SeaNick Don't understand your question.  Especially in a multithreaded environment should shared resources be kept hidden.  Getter/setter functions will allow you to wrap the shared resource in a mutex and avoid race conditions.

Comment: I think your comment just answered my confused question... If you define the variable in two separate .c files, each one might be making bad assumptions about the current state of that register.

Comment: @SeaNick Regarding your example, you're defining only one variable.  Other files that `include` (`extern`) it know the address of it and can directly access it (read/write to it).  Regardless of how many source files `include` it, there is only one variable, not one of each inclusion.

Answer (score 1):

That's exactly right.  You need to have the `extern` in the header in order to tell the compiler that `var1` exists and what its type is when it's compiling code that uses it.

(I'm assuming that you are using `var1` in more than one `.c` file, and one of them is defining it.  If you're only using it in one `.c` file then there's no need for the declaration in the header if you define the variable before using it.)

Comment: So the next question to that would be, does the struct need to be public if the instantiation of it is extern? Couldn't the typedef be moved into the .c and made static or would that result in the compiler not knowing how to to access the fields within it if a different C file referenced the extern variable?

Comment: @SeaNick: The latter.  The compiler needs to have seen the typedef in order to know what the names and types of the structure's members are.

Comment: Does the declaration have to be in that specific header, or is a better practice to simply create an extern declaration in any other .c file that uses that variable?

Comment: @SeaNick: You should put it in the header, then it's only in one place.  Duplication is generally considered a bad thing (the "Don't Repeat Yourself" principle).

Comment: I guess the concern I have with that, is does that imply that the compiler will reserve space for that variable for every file that includes that header, regardless of whether they use that variable? Because that would be using unnecessary code space.

Comment: @SeaNick: No, there's no space reserved.  All the header is doing is saying that something exists elsewhere, and here is some information about it.  The `extern` means "This is external, not defined here, not taking up any space here." (@RSahu's answer explains this well.)